order list not view properly in laravel api
i am a begginer level of laravel.i am doing the warehouse management in laravel i want to assiocate the relationship with many to many and one to many when i view the data i am struck on this line i don't how to get details form product order is it correct i need to get the qty on the product order. can any one help me to complete index funtion of ordercontroller load. client table and order table and product order how to view the data as json :
 foreach ($order->products as $product) 
            {
                $arrayobj['order_products'][] = [
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'product_name' => $product->name, 
                    

                ];

            }

Here is the Full code :
here is code of product and client and order and order product  i need you to correct with order api part index and store function inside the order controller  :
client
class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "clients";
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'address',
    ];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

product
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "products";

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_code',
        'product_name',
        'stock_level',
        'price',
        'category_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'product_orders');
    }

order
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "orders";


    protected $fillable = [
        'order_number',
        'total',
        'client_id',  
    ];



    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_orders');
    }

}

ProductOrder
class ProductOrder extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "product_orders";

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'order_id',
        'qty',
    ];
}

here is the order controller
// retrieve data from clinet
public function index()
{

    $orders = Order::with(['client', 'products'])->get();

    // create empty array
    $response_array = [];

    // loop orders

    foreach ($orders as $order) 
        {
                $arrayobj = [
                    'order_number' => $order->order_number,
                    'client_id' => $order->client_id,
                    'total' => $order->total,
                    'order_products' => []
                ];

    foreach ($order->products as $product) 
        {
            $arrayobj['order_products'][] = [
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'product_name' => $product->name, 
            ];

        }


        // array_push()
    }

    return    $response_array;
}


You are missing 'qty' => $product->pivot->qty, in the foreach loop with that setup.

And of course if its API you should return json like : return response()->json($response_array);

that is the only thing do it sir.         array_push() method how to  call it

can you write the full code it is much easiler to get understand

ProductOrder order also i need to make the relationship

just assign the $arrayobj table to response: $response_array[] = $arrayobj;

ProductOrder how to make the relationship please check it.i haven't add the relationship

For pivot you don't need to define Model, its obligatory.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You don't need to create Model strictly for Pivot. It's obligatory.
For Order model you can define relationship like:
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('qty');
}

and for Product:
public function orders()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('qty');
}

Then you can access to Pivot like:
foreach ($order->products as $product) {
        $orderData['order_products'][] = [
            /// ...
            'qty' => $product->pivot->qty // Access to the Pivot 
        ];
    }

    return response()->json($orderData);


ProductOrder model we no need to make a relationship sir

protected $fillable = [
'product_id',
'order_id',
'qty',
];   here is the productorder model
